# SQL Server AlwaysOn Availability Groups Cluster File Share Permissions

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering

Just need to double confirm, when setting up the file share witness to act as a quorum vote in the HA cluster - does each server node within the cluster need access to that file share or is it just the cluster name that needs write access to the file share?

Pretty sure its just the cluster object name that needs access to the file share but want to be doubly sure

Answer (score 1):

> HA cluster - does each server node within the cluster need access to that file share or is it just the cluster name that needs write access to the file share?

Each node participating in WSFC should have access to the FS witness and the WSFC name or cluster name object( CNO) should have read write permission on fileshare folder and also at NTFS level.

A FS witness should not be part of WSFC and can reside on "any" windows machine which is accessible to both the nodes. Please note that the file share witness should reside on one of the machines which is part of domain in which WSFC is created.

Comment: Microsoft documentation only mentions that the cluster CNO needs permissions: Must have write permissions enabled for the computer object for the cluster name - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/manage-cluster-quorum

This permission is automatically granted when you add the file share as a witness in the failover cluster manager

Comment: @DanielNash The permission would not be granted automatically, it has happened to me many a time when I need to specifically add the permission. I have mentioned same thing as docs mention just that CNO in docs means WSFC name